# In flask, can I not name a session variable using another varible?

Tags: python, flask, session-variables

Im trying to do:

```
@app.route("/process_page_data/<page>", methods=["POST"])
def process_page_data(page):

    print(f"\n process {page} data... \n")

    session[f"{page}"] = list(request.form.items())
    print(f"\n{session[page]=}")

    return "Hello World"
```

This is what I get in my terminal:

```
 process page1 data...


session[page]=[('q1', '1'), ('q2', '1'), ('q3', '1'), ('q4', '1'), ('q5', '1'), ('q6', '1'), ('q7', '1'), ('q8', '1'), ('q9', '1'), ('q10', '1'), ('q11', '1'), ('q12', '1'), ('q13', '1'), ('q14', '1'), ('q15', '1')]
```

I'm trying to get it as: session['page1'] but I'm not sure why it isn't working! Haven't seen anywhere else online about this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with flask or sessions but the printing of f strings with `=` and an expectation that this should expand one variable name but not the other

Comment: You're right! I printed out the entire session variable instead and found it did what I wanted to! (print(f"\n{session}=")

Thank you!